# Nullable double

Tags: java, null, double

Here's a quick question. How do I initialize a double to null? As in when the level is empty, it will require the user to input a data. Else, if the data has already been inputted, it will ask user to overwrite the save changes. From my code below, I can only run the "if(level == null){" and not the overwrite statement

```
public static void inValue() {
  double level = null; 
  if(level == null){
      System.out.println("Enter level: ");
         level = sc.nextDouble();
         pat1.setLevel(level);
         break;      
  }
  else{
     System.out.println("Overwrite");                           
     System.out.println("Enter level: ");
     level = sc.nextDouble();
     pat1.setLevel(level);
     break;     
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Use a `java.lang.Double` instead of primitive `double`.

A `Double` extends `Object` and is nullable.

For instance:

```
Double level = null;
```

API [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html).

**Notes**

- In your case, only the `if` statement will execute, since `level` is declared as `null` outside the `if` / `else` scope.
- Your `break` statements are useless in this context.

Comment: An addendum onto this: if you are going to compare the Double object with another Double object, use .equals() or .doubleValue() for the comparison.  Otherwise it will look at the actual object references.  I've seen more than one programmer puzzle over this.

Comment: I did the same thing, and it still gives the similar output. Can you explain it more detail?

Comment: @user3676202 my answer is on how to use nullable `double` types. If you are having another issue you are probably going to have to ask a different question - although I'm editing my answer with the obvious.

Answer (score 1):

To assign a `null`value tu a double, you have to use the `java.lang.Double`class.

But that's only one part of your problem.
Every time you call `inValue()`, you set your `level`to `null`.
So `level==null` is always true.

You have to declare your `level`object outside this function so it will keep the previous value.